# How to get rid of empty view screen which appears every time i resume activity?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-asynctask, simplecursoradapter

I have a SimpleCursorAdapter and a List in my main activity. I have set an emptyView to be shown when there are no items present in the database. But the AsyncTask creates a new list everytime for onResume. So I get the emptyView screen for a fractional second before the list loads. Now I need the AsyncTask as data query has to run on separate thread. But I dont like the emptyView popping up every time. I have attached my AsyncTask and onResume methods below. Both are compiling. How do I go about it?

```
class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Cursor> {
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper (MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
        dbHelper.open();
        return dbHelper.getAllItems();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        adapter.changeCursor(result);
        dbHelper.close();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new GetItems().execute((Object[]) null);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use a `ListFragment`, you can call `setListShown(false)` on task start, which shows a loading spinner. On task end, you call `setListShown(true)`, then call `setEmptyText()` to place some error message or empty message depending on results of the task.

Or simple switch visibility:

```
class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Cursor> {
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper (MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myListView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
        dbHelper.open();
        return dbHelper.getAllItems();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        adapter.changeCursor(result);
        myListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dbHelper.close();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new GetItems().execute((Object[]) null);

}
```

Comment: I am using an activity with a list in it.

Comment: @user1971924 Then you can go with `setVisibility(GONE)` to `setVisibility(VISIBLE)` on ListView.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be a Threading thing, where you fire off the AsyncTask and your `onResume` finishes, then your view is blank while you're waiting for the AyncTask to finish.

One fix that comes to mind is to fire off the AsyncTask earlier in the Activity lifecycle (e.g. the onCreate or onStart methods), which might get you the results in time for the first load.

You could then store the retrieved results, and if the user just navigates away then comes back without the Activity being destroyed, you could load the old list, then refresh it once you'd retrieved the updated one using the AsyncTask.

**Edit**
Another simple fix would be to put a progress dialog in the `onPre` and `onPostExecute` methods of the AsyncTask, which would make the UI thread block until the result was retrieved, but the flashing up of a progress dialog might be more jarring than the blank screen

Comment: I have another activity where I add items to the list. As soon as this addItem activity is done, Main Activity (the one with the list) should appear. So I cannot have the list in either of onCreate or onStart as the list changes frequently. I will try using onPre and onPostExecute methods.

Comment: i tried a loading spinner in the onPre method. But the UI goes onPre, then emptyView and then List. Need to think of a way to pass the old cursor into the onResume method.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you start the spinner in onPre, and cancel it in onPost, and by then your processing has all finished